# Optimising a sed grep regex shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have managed to create a working shell script (OS X) that seems to do what I want it to do (with little to no prior experience with shell). However, even though it seems to work, it does so rather slowly -- so I'm wondering if there are any obvious tweaks that would optimize performance.

So basically what the code does is that it passes a file through a python script to a REST API, and then it parses the resulting text (gets the 'lemma'-s out of it and assembles them into a continous string).

The text that we get back from the REST API looks something like this:

```
filename
form wsafter anas
Szekó_József " " []
fideszes " " [{"lemma": "fideszes", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "Fidesz[/N]=fidesz+es[_Adjz:s/Adj]=es+[Nom]=", "readable": "Fidesz[/N]=fidesz + es[_Adjz:s/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "f:F i:i d:d e:e s:s z:z :[/N] e:e s:s :[_Adjz:s/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "fideszes", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "Fidesz[/N]=fidesz+es[_Nz:s/N]=es+[Nom]=", "readable": "Fidesz[/N]=fidesz + es[_Nz:s/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "f:F i:i d:d e:e s:s z:z :[/N] e:e s:s :[_Nz:s/N] :[Nom]"}]
polgármester " " [{"lemma": "polgármester", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "polgár[/N]=polgár+mester[/N]=mester+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgár[/N] + mester[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r :[/N] m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "polgármester[/N]=polgármester+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgármester[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom]"}]
tragikus " " [{"lemma": "tragikus", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "tragikus[/Adj]=tragikus+[Nom]=", "readable": "tragikus[/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "t:t r:r a:a g:g i:i k:k u:u s:s :[/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "tragikus", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "tragikus[/N]=tragikus+[Nom]=", "readable": "tragikus[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "t:t r:r a:a g:g i:i k:k u:u s:s :[/N] :[Nom]"}]
halála " " [{"lemma": "halál", "tag": "[/N][Poss.3Sg][Nom]", "morphana": "halál[/N]=halál+a[Poss.3Sg]=a+[Nom]=", "readable": "halál[/N] + a[Poss.3Sg] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "h:h a:a l:l á:á l:l :[/N] a:a :[Poss.3Sg] :[Nom]"}]
után " " [{"lemma": "után", "tag": "[/Post]", "morphana": "után[/Post]=után", "readable": "után[/Post]", "twolevel": "u:u t:t á:á n:n :[/Post]"}]
egy " " [{"lemma": "egy", "tag": "[/Det|Art.NDef]", "morphana": "egy[/Det|Art.NDef]=egy", "readable": "egy[/Det|Art.NDef]", "twolevel": "e:e g:g y:y :[/Det|Art.NDef]"}, {"lemma": "egy", "tag": "[/Num][Nom]", "morphana": "egy[/Num]=egy+[Nom]=", "readable": "egy[/Num] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "e:e g:g y:y :[/Num] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "egy", "tag": "[/N|Pro][Nom]", "morphana": "egy[/N|Pro]=egy+[Nom]=", "readable": "egy[/N|Pro] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "e:e g:g y:y :[/N|Pro] :[Nom]"}]
polgármester-jelölt " " [{"lemma": "polgármester-jelöl", "tag": "[/V][Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "morphana": "polgár[/N]=polgár+mester[/N]=mester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelöl[/V]=jelöl+t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]=t", "readable": "polgár[/N] + mester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelöl[/V] + t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r :[/N] m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l :[/V] t:t :[Pst.NDef.3Sg]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester-jelölt", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "polgár[/N]=polgár+mester[/N]=mester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelöl[/V]=jelöl+t[_PerfPtcp/Adj]=t+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgár[/N] + mester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelöl[/V] + t[_PerfPtcp/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r :[/N] m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l :[/V] t:t :[_PerfPtcp/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester-jelölt", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "polgár[/N]=polgár+mester[/N]=mester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelölt[/N]=jelölt+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgár[/N] + mester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelölt[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r :[/N] m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l t:t :[/N] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester-jelöl", "tag": "[/V][Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "morphana": "polgármester[/N]=polgármester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelöl[/V]=jelöl+t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]=t", "readable": "polgármester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelöl[/V] + t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l :[/V] t:t :[Pst.NDef.3Sg]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester-jelölt", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "polgármester[/N]=polgármester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelöl[/V]=jelöl+t[_PerfPtcp/Adj]=t+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgármester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelöl[/V] + t[_PerfPtcp/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l :[/V] t:t :[_PerfPtcp/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "polgármester-jelölt", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "polgármester[/N]=polgármester+[Nom]=+-[Hyph:Hyph]=-+jelölt[/N]=jelölt+[Nom]=", "readable": "polgármester[/N] + [Nom] + -[Hyph:Hyph] + jelölt[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "p:p o:o l:l g:g á:á r:r m:m e:e s:s t:t e:e r:r :[/N] :[Nom] -:- :[Hyph:Hyph] j:j e:e l:l ö:ö l:l t:t :[/N] :[Nom]"}]
maradt " " [{"lemma": "marad", "tag": "[/V][Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "morphana": "marad[/V]=marad+t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]=t", "readable": "marad[/V] + t[Pst.NDef.3Sg]", "twolevel": "m:m a:a r:r a:a d:d :[/V] t:t :[Pst.NDef.3Sg]"}, {"lemma": "maradt", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "marad[/V]=marad+t[_PerfPtcp/Adj]=t+[Nom]=", "readable": "marad[/V] + t[_PerfPtcp/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "m:m a:a r:r a:a d:d :[/V] t:t :[_PerfPtcp/Adj] :[Nom]"}]
a " " [{"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/Det|Art.Def]", "morphana": "a[/Det|Art.Def]=a", "readable": "a[/Det|Art.Def]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/Det|Art.Def]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/Det|Pro|(Post)]", "morphana": "a[/Det|Pro|(Post)]=a", "readable": "a[/Det|Pro|(Post)]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/Det|Pro|(Post)]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "a[/N|Ltr]=a+[Nom]=", "readable": "a[/N|Ltr] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/N|Ltr] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/N|Pro|(Post)][Nom]", "morphana": "a[/N|Pro|(Post)]=a+[Nom]=", "readable": "a[/N|Pro|(Post)] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/N|Pro|(Post)] :[Nom]"}]
Baranya " " [{"lemma": "Baranya", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "Baranya[/N]=Baranya+[Nom]=", "readable": "Baranya[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "B:B a:a r:r a:a n:n y:y a:a :[/N] :[Nom]"}]
megyei " " [{"lemma": "megyei", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "megye[/N]=megye+i[_Adjz:i/Adj]=i+[Nom]=", "readable": "megye[/N] + i[_Adjz:i/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "m:m e:e g:g y:y e:e :[/N] i:i :[_Adjz:i/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "megyei", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "megyei[/Adj]=megyei+[Nom]=", "readable": "megyei[/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "m:m e:e g:g y:y e:e i:i :[/Adj] :[Nom]"}]
településen "" [{"lemma": "település", "tag": "[/N][Supe]", "morphana": "telep[/N]=telep+ül[/V]=ül+és[_Ger/N]=és+en[Supe]=en", "readable": "telep[/N] + ül[/V] + és[_Ger/N] + en[Supe]", "twolevel": "t:t e:e l:l e:e p:p :[/N] ü:ü l:l :[/V] é:é s:s :[_Ger/N] e:e n:n :[Supe]"}, {"lemma": "település", "tag": "[/N][Supe]", "morphana": "telep[/N]=telep+ülés[/N]=ülés+en[Supe]=en", "readable": "telep[/N] + ülés[/N] + en[Supe]", "twolevel": "t:t e:e l:l e:e p:p :[/N] ü:ü l:l é:é s:s :[/N] e:e n:n :[Supe]"}, {"lemma": "település", "tag": "[/N][Supe]", "morphana": "települ[/V]=települ+és[_Ger/N]=és+en[Supe]=en", "readable": "települ[/V] + és[_Ger/N] + en[Supe]", "twolevel": "t:t e:e l:l e:e p:p ü:ü l:l :[/V] é:é s:s :[_Ger/N] e:e n:n :[Supe]"}, {"lemma": "település", "tag": "[/N][Supe]", "morphana": "település[/N]=település+en[Supe]=en", "readable": "település[/N] + en[Supe]", "twolevel": "t:t e:e l:l e:e p:p ü:ü l:l é:é s:s :[/N] e:e n:n :[Supe]"}]
, " " [{"lemma": ",", "tag": "[Punct]", "morphana": "", "readable": "", "twolevel": ""}]
a " " [{"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/Det|Art.Def]", "morphana": "a[/Det|Art.Def]=a", "readable": "a[/Det|Art.Def]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/Det|Art.Def]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/Det|Pro|(Post)]", "morphana": "a[/Det|Pro|(Post)]=a", "readable": "a[/Det|Pro|(Post)]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/Det|Pro|(Post)]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "a[/N|Ltr]=a+[Nom]=", "readable": "a[/N|Ltr] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/N|Ltr] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "a", "tag": "[/N|Pro|(Post)][Nom]", "morphana": "a[/N|Pro|(Post)]=a+[Nom]=", "readable": "a[/N|Pro|(Post)] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "a:a :[/N|Pro|(Post)] :[Nom]"}]
szocialista " " [{"lemma": "szocialista", "tag": "[/Adj][Nom]", "morphana": "szocialista[/Adj]=szocialista+[Nom]=", "readable": "szocialista[/Adj] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "s:s z:z o:o c:c i:i a:a l:l i:i s:s t:t a:a :[/Adj] :[Nom]"}, {"lemma": "szocialista", "tag": "[/N][Nom]", "morphana": "szocialista[/N]=szocialista+[Nom]=", "readable": "szocialista[/N] + [Nom]", "twolevel": "s:s z:z o:o c:c i:i a:a l:l i:i s:s t:t a:a :[/N] :[Nom]"}]
Csorbai_Ferenc "" []
, " " [{"lemma": ",", "tag": "[Punct]", "morphana": "", "readable": "", "twolevel": ""}]
( "" [{"lemma": "(", "tag": "[Punct]", "morphana": "", "readable": "", "twolevel": ""}]
```

The expected result:

```
Szekó_József fideszes polgármester tragikus halál után egy polgármester-jelöl marad a Baranya megyei település , a szocialista Csorbai_Ferenc , (
```

Here is the script itself:

```
#! /bin/bash

CV=1
for file in /Users/balintkis/tdk/budapest-onk-valasztas/bigramizalt-nev-support/*
do
    echo $file
    tempfilename="/Users/balintkis/tdk/budapest-onk-valasztas/bigramizalt-nev-support-result/temp$CV.txt"

    szoveg=$(python3 docker-py.py $file) 

    echo "$szoveg" >> $tempfilename
    sed -E -i "" "1,2d" $tempfilename
    sed -i "" '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' $tempfilename

    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        lemmacount=$(echo "$line" | egrep -c '\[{\"lemma\": \".*?\"')
        if [ "$lemmacount" -ge "1" ]
        then
            sp0=$(echo "$line" | egrep -o '\[{\"lemma\": \".*?\"')
            sp=${sp0:12}
            sp=${sp%?}
            sp=$sp" "
            echo -n "$sp" >> /Users/balintkis/tdk/budapest-onk-valasztas/bigramizalt-nev-support-result/kiir$CV.txt
        else
            sp=$(echo "$line" | sed -E 's|.*\[\](.*)\[\/.*|\1|g')
            sp=$(echo $sp | sed -E 's|\s*(.*)\s*|\1|g')
            echo -n "$sp " >> /Users/balintkis/tdk/budapest-onk-valasztas/bigramizalt-nev-support-result/kiir$CV.txt
       fi
    done < "$tempfilename"

    rm $tempfilename
    CV=$((CV+1))
done
```

Thanks for any suggestions and please be as explicit with suggestions as you can be (ideally with code suggestions), seeing that I'm all pretty new to this. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you add your (expected) output for the shown input file? This would make it far easier to understand what you are doing than having to read your script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Socowi Added it. Oguz Ismail: Ah, didn't know CodeReview SE existed...

Comment: Unfortunately you should start over writing an awk (or python I guess since you already call python) script instead of a shell script as this is a completely inappropriate application for a shell script which is why it's so slow and buggy. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Agree with Ed Morton. Use the right tool!. Perl, Python, or JQ

Comment: The expected result has words like 'erre', can not be found in the input !

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I've originally posted a shortened input (it would have been too huge), and I've matched the output accordingly now.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you one starting point here, and it's the basic usage of `grep`:

Imagine you have a file, which looks like this:

```
info1
info2
blabla
info3
more blabla
```

You want to do something with all lines, containing `info`.

You seem to do the following (pseudo-code):

```
while readline(<filename>)
do
  use "grep" to see if the word "info" is on that line. In that case, do something
done
```

This can be done in an easier way like this (`grep` is automatically checking every line in the file):

```
grep "info" <filename> | do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify the question - sample output does not match input. However, based on some assumptions, using awk to filter/JQ to parse JSON

```
cat resp.txt |
    awk 'BEGIN { print "[" } END { print "[] ]" } /lemma/ { sub("^[^[]*. ", ""); print $0, "," }' | 
    jq '.[][].lemma' |
    uniq |
    tr -d '"' |
    tr '\n' ' '
```

The result looks like below. You should be able to merge them

```
fideszes polgármester tragikus halál után egy polgármester-jelöl polgármester-jelölt polgármester-jelöl polgármester-jelölt marad
```

awk is needed to extract the JSON from the response. jq to extract the lemma's.

Consider changing the output file to be JSON only. It will be much easier to use a single tool (jq) to parse it.

Comment: Hello - this seems to exclude the words whenever the rest api cannot recognize a valid lemma for the input - in which case the desired output is to just to leave the input the same as was. See the first line for an example -- "Szekó_József". This is what the if does in my code.

Comment: @user3616457 It is not easy to reverse engineer (un-commented) code with input/output in Hungarian. Consider posting clear, complete requirement to the original question.

Comment: Or just modify the proposed solution to add the missing behavior.